# R stopwords: getting rid of ALL the words starting with 'https'

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, stop-words

I'm doing a project that includes Twitter scraping.

The problem: I don't seem to be able to remove ALL of the words that start with 'https'.

My code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(tm)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(e1017)
library(class)
library(wordcloud)
library(tidytext)

scraped_tweets <- searchTwitter('Silk Sonic - leave door open', n = 10000, lang='en')

# get text data from tweets
scraped_text <- sapply(scraped_tweets, function(x){x$getText()})


# removing emojis and characters
scraped_text <- iconv(scraped_text, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')

scraped_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(scraped_text))

doc_matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(scraped_corpus, control = list(removePunctuation=T,
                                      stopwords = c('https','http', 'sonic', 
                                               'silk',stopwords('english')),
                                                removeNumbers = T,tolower = T))


# convert object into a matrix
doc_matrix <- as.matrix(doc_matrix)


# get word counts

head(doc_matrix,1)

words <- sort(rowSums(doc_matrix), decreasing = T)

dm <- data.frame(word = names(words), freq = words)


# wordcloud

wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, random.order = F, colors = brewer.pal(8, 'Dark2'))
```

I added the tags 'https' and 'http', but it didn't help.
I can of course clean the output with gsub but it's not the same as I still get the rest of the link name as an output.

Are there any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the [documentation for the `tm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf):

> stopwords Either a Boolean value indicating stopword removal using default
> language specific stopword lists shipped with this package, a character vec-
> tor holding custom stopwords, or a custom function for stopword removal.
> Defaults to FALSE.

The stopwords argument does not seem to make any partial or pattern matches on the provided stopwords. It does accept a custom function, though. This is one option, but I think it is easiest to do the url removal on the character vector before even turning it into a corpus:

```r
scraped_text <- sapply(scraped_tweets, function(x){x$getText()})
scraped_text <- iconv(scraped_text, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')

# Added line for regex string removal
scraped_text <- str_remove_all(scraped_text, r"(https?://[^)\]\s]+(?=[)\]\s]))")


scraped_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(scraped_text))
```

This is a rather simple regex for url recognition, but it works reasonably well. There are more complicated ones out there, which can easily be found with a google search.

Comment: Yeah, I used regex at the end as well, I was just hoping that I didn't know about something more sophisticated.